# Assignments to the 'toLoadNumber' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, console

I have a problem in the console that shows
[eslint]
src\pages\Contact\Contact.jsx
Line 15:22:  Assignments to the 'toLoadNumber' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

```
export const Contact = () => {
useEffect(() => {
// Anything in here is fired on component mount.
return () => {
  // Anything in here is fired on component unmount.
  toLoadNumber = 0;
};
}, []);
const location = useLocation();
let { toLoadNumber } = location.state || 0;
const formRef = useRef(null);
const [formvalue, setFormvalue] = useState({
name: "",
email: "",
contact: "",
message: "",
});
```

Comment: where did you define toLoadNumber variable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe according to your use case, the code looks fine, however es-lint is designed to help enforce coding practices, they might suit this code though.

So you can just go ahead and disable the error given by es-lint using

`//eslint-disable-next-line`

You shouldn't use this to escape every problem. However, in this case you have no choice.